# Spring boot - How to customize http request error 400 instead of https

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating a Restful API and I want JSON responses. I enabled Https by default and when I try to access endpoints with http protocol I get a 400 error with this response message:

> Bad Request This combination of host and port requires TLS.

I want to return a JSON object instead, something like:

```
{
   "message": "Bad Request HTTPS required",
   "status": 400,
   "timestamp": "2022-04-13T12:05:25.332"
}
```

How can I implement this in Spring Boot??

Comment: Why? Instead of blocking those requests, why not redirect them to the https counter part? That would be way more friendly...

Comment: I tried to redirect from http to https but this operation works using both from one port to the other (let's say 8080 to 8443)-. I want use only https, (no http)

Comment: You should configure tomcat to allow only https and that all HTTP traffic is automatically routed to https. I don't really get your comment.

Comment: I followed this tutorial here https://o7planning.org/11867/configure-spring-boot-to-redirect-http-to-https#a18123094 (second method) but it works only for redirect pages from http on a specific port number to https on another specific port number both configured in application.properties.

Comment: Ofcourse as it has little use if you don't use a port.. You always have a port default 80 for http and 443 for https. Unless you don't directly connect to the internet it generally is 8080/8443. If there is nothing listening you wouldn't even get a connection (a 404 which you couldn't do anything about).

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't exposed the question correctly. The point is that the message I want to modify is the message I get when I try to connect with http protocol on the 8443 port (the https port).

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Exception handler with the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation and cach any Exception, with the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation, and then return with a custom json response.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler {

   //The exception can be different or eather a list of exceptions like value = { ExceptionType1.class, ExceptionType2.class}  
   @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
   public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBadRequestException(BadRequestException e) {

     HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;

     CustomResponseClass response = new CustomResponseClass(CustomEnum.RESPONSE_CODE, e.getMessage(), httpStatus.value(), ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z")));
     
     return new ResponseEntity<>(response, httpStatus);
   }


}
```

Comment: BadRequestException is not found. Am I missing something?

Comment: Here you can read more about this topic. https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api